# R: How do I put two box plots next to each other, keeping same y-range for both?

Tags: r, plotmath

Let's say I have two data sets, one with y-range [min0:max0] and the other with y-range [min1:max1]. How can put both box plots in one plot next to each other with a sane y-range [min(min0, min1):max(max0, max1)]?

Here's what I tried:

```
d0 <- matrix(rnorm(15), ncol=3)
d1 <- matrix(rnorm(15), ncol=3)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
boxplot(d0)
usr <- par("usr")
plot.new()
par(usr = usr)
boxplot(d1, add = TRUE)
```

But that will only keep the first plots y-range and also squeeze both plots whereas I'd like them to be square.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for the hint; it now is.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
d0 <- matrix(rnorm(15), ncol=3)
d1 <- matrix(rnorm(15), ncol=3)

# Using base R graphics
lmts <- range(d0,d1)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
boxplot(d0,ylim=lmts)
boxplot(d1,ylim=lmts)
```

[image: base graphics plot]

You may also want to think about a way to do this using grid graphics, either by the `lattice` or `ggplot2` packages.

Here's one attempt in ggplot2:

```
# Using ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(d.type=c(rep(0,15),rep(1,15)),sub.type=rep(c('A','B','C'),10),val=rnorm(30))

p <- ggplot(d, aes(factor(sub.type), val)) 
p + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(. ~ d.type)
```

[image: ggplot2]

And in lattice:

```
# Using lattice
library(lattice)
bwplot(~ val|sub.type+d.type ,d)
```

[image: lattice plot]

Note how the grid-based solutions keep you from ever having to specify limits; you specify structure and the software does the rest.

Comment: Hmpf, I probably have read over boxplot's ylim argument. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 for the extensive answer, thanks again!

Comment: Nah, a *really* extensive answer would have included slices (lattice), aesthetics (ggplot2), and other ways to make the grid-based graphics look prettier :-)

Comment: Err, that's shingles not slices.

Comment: `lmts` can be calculated more succinctly via: `lmts <- range(d0,d1)`.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: Thanks, updated.  Sometimes you look back at your own code and just shake your head :-).  Path dependence in action.

Comment: @gsk: In my case s/sometimes/always.  I just saw that line and thought, "there has to be a lazier way to get that result". ;-)

Comment: @JU: Yeah, I sort of took the " [min(min0, min1):max(max0, max1)]" from the original question and R-ified it.  So as the Perl manual says, it's about being lazy the right way, not about being lazy the way that involves more typing and less thought!